# Regex containing a specific word

Tags: c#, regex

I need load files from directory same this example: "Client_Test_delete.xlsx". But loading all
files with _delete.xlsx extension. How create valid testMask?

```
var testMask = @"^[Client]+(.*_delete.xlsx*).*$";
var searchPattern = new Regex(testMask, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var files = Directory.GetFiles(fullPath).Where(f => searchPattern.IsMatch(f));
```

Files in directory:

```
c:\Client_Test_delete.xlsx"
c:\Some_Test_delete.xlsx"
```

Comment: Try to learn regular expressions. They are not complicated at all. An important note: your random attempts won't ever work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The System.IO.Directory.GetFiles has an overload that have a search pattern, try this. It's more simple.
[i don't know the regular expressions]

http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms143316%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Indeed. In this case Regex is not necessary. Add the English link here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
  string txt="Client_Test_delete.xlsx";

  string re1="(Client)";    // Word 1
  string re2=".*?"; // Non-greedy match on filler
  string re3="_";   // Uninteresting: c
  string re4=".*?"; // Non-greedy match on filler
  string re5="(_)"; // Any Single Character 1
  string re6="(delete)";    // Word 2
  string re7="(\\.)";   // Any Single Character 2
  string re8="(xlsx)";  // Variable Name 1

  Regex r = new Regex(re1+re2+re3+re4+re5+re6+re7+re8,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase|RegexOptions.Singleline);
  Match m = r.Match(txt);
  if (m.Success)
  {
     //Delete file
  }
```

Comment: Updated so it includes the word 'Client'

Answer (score 1):

try with this regex:

> ^(?:[\w]\:)+\*(Client).*?_.*?_delete.xlsx

I update the expression with Client part.

It Match: "c:\Client_Test_delete.xlsx"
and fail with "c:\Some_Test_delete.xlsx"

Comment: I need first word "Client"

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
var testMask = @"^Client_[a-z\d]+_delete.xlsx?$";   // OR "^Client_[^_]+_delete.xlsx?$"
var searchPattern = new Regex(testMask, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var files = Directory.GetFiles(fullPath).Where(f => searchPattern.IsMatch(f));
```

This will match files with `.xlsx` or `.xls` extensions, and first word `client` and last word `delete`.

Hope it will give you an idea to go ahead.